# Tail probability of minimum to maximum ratio among $n$ i.i.d. half-normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request, order-statistics

I have $n$ i.i.d.$\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random variables $X_1,\cdots,\ X_n$. For my research, I am interested in finding bounds (upper and lower) of the tail probabilities of the ratio $\frac{|X|_{(1)}}{|X|_{(n)}}$, where $|X|_{(1)}$ and $|X|_{(n)}$ are the minimum and maximum among $|X_1|,\cdots, |X_n|$, respectively. While I am able to find some bounds, I am not sure how well they fare compared to exisitng results. But I couldn't find anything in the literature about these bounds. Can anyone kindly refer to me some of the relevant literature. Kindly **do not provide a full answer**, and only point to refrences. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about sharing the bounds you have established? I'd be curious to know how well they compare with simulation results and also if they get tighter for large $n$.

Comment: @AdityaDua, actually these bounds I have derived is a work in progress and are part of my ongoing research project, so I am not sure if I can openly discuss those. However, I can tell you that I have found a lower bound on $P(R>a)$,($R$ is the ratio in question), which is exactly matching when $a=0$, but is very small when $a=1$, and depends on $n$, which however should not be the case and the value at $a=1$ should be exactly $1$.

Comment: Also, they actually get very small when $n$ is very large, so yes those are not good bounds.